# Kepler RCP CoolBar + PerspectiveBar appearance

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, toolbar, perspective, kepler

The coolbars on all Kepler RCP applications look just terrible. This a project created from scratch on Windows 8.

What is it with that thick black line sorrounding the coolbar? 
Can it be style-hacked with CSS?

From my testing, it seems that it appears only when the perspective bar is present.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the CSS for this is the `eclipse-perspective-keyline-color` in the `#PerspectiveSwitcher` selector.

Comment: Oh damn, gonna test this. How'd you figure that out? CSS Spy?

Comment: I have done quite a bit with CSS for my pure E4 RCPs so I have a fair idea what does what. CSS Spy can be quite useful but it can still be hard to work out some things. I tested this by hacking the Eclipse CSS (but this is on a Mac so may vary from Windows).

Comment: Didn't complicate myself with CSS. Just removed the perspective switcher.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this dependencies in your product file: **org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core**, **org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt**.