# Eclipse SDK4: ugly perspective bar border

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am migrating `RCP app` to `Eclipse 4` . And I'm stuck with problem: perspective bar has really ugly bold borders, I can't understand why, frankly no idea.

If I disable perspective bar through `IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer.setShowPerspectiveBar(false)` there are no ugly borders.
Spent 2 days googling without any results.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Related question**: [Kepler RCP CoolBar + PerspectiveBar appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546429/kepler-rcp-coolbar-perspectivebar-appearance)

You will have to play around with CSS. I would start from adding a simple CSS file to the RCP App, and changing the color for the `eclipse-perspective-keyline-color`. [See an example of a theme here (line 76)](https://gist.github.com/golimpio/3096330).

**Other possible solution**: Hide the whole perspective switcher.

`configurer.setShowPerspectiveBar(false);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Did you figure out how to customize css for RCP app to change this thing?

Comment: @Steve Actually no, I didn't bother. I just hid the whole damn thing. I modified the above answer and added directions to the CSS config of the app.